# How use \DeclarePairedDelimiterX after \providecommand* for same command?

Tags: macros, math-operators, mathtools

The package `mismath` includes the definition:

```
\providecommand*{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
```

After loading `mathtools`, I want to redefine `\abs` by:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\abs}[1]\lvert\rvert{#1}
\newcommand{\Abs}[1]{\set*{#1}}
\newcommand{\bigabs}[1]{\abs[\big]{#1}}
\newcommand{\biggabs}[1]{\abs[\bigg]{#1}}
```

How do I undo or override the definition of `\abs` from `mismath` so as to enable my own definition?

*Example:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% def of \abs already in mismath...
\usepackage{mismath}
% ... causes "Command \abs already defined" from:
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\abs}[1]\lvert\rvert{#1}

\begin{document}
\[
\abs{-2}=2 \text{ and } \abs*{\frac{2^{3}}{\cos\pi}} = 8
\]
\end{document}
```

*Note:* The same issue occurs when I try to redefine `\norm` similarly. Presumably, the method of redefining `\abs` will work for `\norm` too.

Comment: Don't load `mismath`, it's easier. If you really want it (I can't recommend it), do `\let\abs\relax` before doing `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{...}`.

Comment: OK, `\let\abs\relax` fixes it. There are a number of things in `mismath` that are useful to me. Any particular reason so say "Don't load `mismath`"?

Comment: It loads `esvect`, `xspace` and `mathfixs`. It forces many settigs one might want to have control on.

Comment: Those packages loaded by `mismath` are ones I *do* find useful!

Comment: But I found a serious error using `lucimatx` (my preferred package for using the Lucida Bright text and math fonts) together with `mismath`: it causes a "TeX capacity exceeded" dead-stop! . The cause is that `mismath` hard-codes loading `mathfixs` with the latter's `root` option; but `lucimatx` implements its own method for handling spacing of roots. I wound up hacking both `mismath` so as add to it which options are called for `mathfixs`.

Comment: I warned you… Leave it alone.